ebtables/nftables rule for dropping all frames has no effect
Ubuntu 22.04
I recently discovered that there's a tool called ebtables (nft-based) which is described in man EBTABLES(8) as follows:

ebtables is an application program used to set up and maintain the
tables of rules (inside the Linux kernel) that inspect Ethernet
frames.  It is analogous to the iptables application, but less
complicated, due to the fact that the Ethernet protocol is much
simpler than the IP protocol.

To me it appears as it's possible to redirect raw l2 frames based on the l2 address. I tried the simplest rule to drop all frames from all interfaces and expected all connections stop functioning:
sudo ebtables -A INPUT -j DROP

But nothing actually happened, all connection worked as before.
Is ebtables actually working or some preliminary setup needed (like external kernel module)? journalctl, dmesg reports no errors.
